# Input Spark Scala Dataframe Column as Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Relatively new to scala and the Spark API kit but I have a question trying to make use of the vector assembler

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler

to then make use of matrix correlations

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-statistics.html#correlations

The dataframe column is of dtype linalg.Vector

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()

val trainwlabels3 = assembler.transform(trainwlabels2)

trainwlabels3.dtypes(0)

res90: (String, String) = (features,org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7)
```

and yet calling this to an RDD for the statistics tool throws a mismatch error.

```
val data: RDD[Vector] = sc.parallelize(
  trainwlabels3("features")
) 

<console>:80: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Seq[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just select:

```
val features = trainwlabels3.select($"features")
```

Convert to RDD

```
 val featuresRDD = features.rdd
```

and `map`:

```
featuresRDD.map(_.getAs[Vector]("features"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
val rddForStatistics = new VectorAssembler()
   .transform(trainwlabels2)
   .select($"features")
   .as[Vector] //turns Dataset[Row] (a.k.a DataFrame) to DataSet[Vector]
   .rdd
```

However, you should avoid `RDD`s and figure out how to do what you want with the `DataFrame`-based API (in the `spark.ml` package) because working with `RDD`s is all but deprecated in MLlib.